# Swapping objects. Cant get my head around it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Ok if I have 3 objects.

```
ObjectType *objX;
ObjectType *objY;
ObjectType *tempObjHolder;

objX = [[alloc ObjectType] init];
objY = [[alloc ObjectType] init];

// some code to change values in the objX and objY

tempObjHolder = objX;
objX = objY;
objY = tempObjHolder;
```

Am i swapping the objects ok. Or am I confused to how this works. Do i end up making them all point to one object?

What I am trying to do is make ObjX equal to what objY is then make ObjY equal to what ObjX was.

Thanks
-Code

Comment: Your code shouldn't even work. All objects in Obj-C are pointers.

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: Generally, yes you're doing it right. By that I mean the logic here is right. Imagine you have a nickel in your left hand and a dime in your right and you want to swap them, but you can't have more than 1 coin in a hand, how would you do it? You'd put the dime in a temporary place (say a tabletop, unless you could magically grow a third hand!), swap the nickel over to your right, then pick the dime up with your left. That is the logic behind using a temporary pointer here.

Comment: Yes it all seems logical. But at the end they are both pointing too the same object.

Comment: If after the three lines in your question that accomplish the swap your pointers are pointing at the same object, then they were pointing at the same object before the swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a big difference between "equal to" and "pointer to the same." Your example properly swaps them around so the objects at pointers x and y have swapped positions, but are still distinct.

However, because you haven't nil'd out tempObjHolder in your example, both tempObjHolder and objY both point to the same object (that which was originally assigned to objX).

Also, as thyrgle pointed out, you're missing the pointer in your declarations:

```
ObjectType * someObj;
```

Comment: Joshua at what stage should the tempObjHolder be set to nil?

Comment: I tested this out, and objX and ObjY are the same object at the end. Because when i try change objY the result appears in both objX and objY.

Comment: You would nil tempObjHolder as the last step.  This is normally not done, as it is tempObjHolder should be declared so that it goes out of scope when you are done with it.

Answer (score 1):

That is the generic way to swap any two variables, and yes, you're doing it correctly (though the object-creation code before it won't even compile due to the fact that objects must be pointers and `alloc` is not an object).